# white-space style in datagrid asp.net

Tags: asp.net, datagrid, whitespace

I have an ASP.NET datagrid and I would like to use whitespace style on the rows to make the double space to show.

```
.preSpacing
{
white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

The above styling doesn't seem to have any effect on the datagrid rows. 
Is there a way for styling the datagrid to show white spaces without having to replace space with '&nsbp;' ?

Comment: Where you have assign .preSpacing class?

Comment: <asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="Item Code" DataField="ItemCode" ItemStyle-CssClass="preSpacing"></asp:BoundColumn>

Answer (score 0):

Please look [CSS white-space Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp).

According to me you have to build skin property and in **Rowstyle** you need to assign this class.

Please look at this [Skin file for gridview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479342.aspx) for creating skin file.